# How to create an availability test automatically?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-monitoring

I have gone through this document :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#create-a-url-ping-test

I have created an availability test on Azure portal and it works as excepted . But how can I create/configure an availability test using SDK or HTTP request in an application insight ?

As each time we create a new web app on our Azure VMs by our application , we need to monitor this new application , I don't want to create a test manually. I want to create it with the new web application. 
And can availability test ping internal web apps ?
Any guide is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is rest api [Web Tests - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/webtests/createorupdate) for creating Availability testing, you can take use of it to create or update the Availability test for Application insights.

For a simple way, you can just click the "Try it" button, then fill in all the necessary fields, like below:

[image]

For internal website, if we cannot visit it outside, then availability test can not ping it either.